# Ubuntu 14.04 Wifi problems and blinking

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04

I'm new to ubuntu and i'm having all sorts of problems,

My wifi connection is super slow and intermittent, sometimes it randomly disconnects so I was wondering how do I go about to update the drivers for the adapter?

Also, it keeps blinking when transfering data which I find extremely annoying, I have read and tried diferrent solutions about editing the **wlan.conf** file and adding **options iwlwifi led_mode=1** but it doesn't work for me, and I'm guessing it has something to do with the driver, I feel like i'm missing a line or using a setting for an intels adapter rather than an atheros.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits in a HP Pavilion DV7-1245dx.

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:24:2b:21:93:d7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=3.13.0-29-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.2.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

Comment: possible duplicate - http://askubuntu.com/questions/88103/wireless-led-doesnt-stop-blinking-on-an-hp-dv5-with-an-atheros-ar5007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the dependencies required to compile the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
```

Go [here](http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/) and download the newest driver to your computer then place the file on your desktop and right click and extract here.

Then compile the driver using the directions below.

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.15-rc1-1
make defconfig-ath5k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv ath5k 
sudo modprobe -v ath5k
```

When you have an upgrade to the kernel you will need to do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.15-rc1-1
make clean
make defconfig-ath5k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv ath5k 
sudo modprobe -v ath5k
```

Comment: That actually made it worse, I couldn't connect to my network, the little wifi Icon on the top bar kept searching... Also, do you know if there's a fix for the blinking wifi led for atheros adapters? Should I add the options led_mode=1 in the ath5k.conf file?

Comment: Added directions to install new driver and hopefully that will fix your blinking issue too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but apparently that didn't do it either, I don't know if i'm doing something wrong, but after I put in the commands both times, what happens is that the wifi icon on the top keeps searching, even when "connected" to my network. After I reboot the computer it finally connected but the blinking continues

Comment: Have the disconnects stopped?

Comment: Yes it looks like they have, but the led still blinking everytime it sends/receives data

Comment: That is a separate issue, only one issue per question is allowed, if you will start a new question about the blinking issue I will try to help you with it but I am not sure we can fix it but I will try. Please accept this answer as the fix for your disconnection issue so everyone can benefit from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I temporarily solved this problem on Ubuntu 14.04 by running command:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M
```