# Ubuntu Mate 14.04 blinking wifi light HP G60

Tags: wireless, hp, mate

I know this question has been asked before and has been answered several times in askubuntu.

I have tried the advice (Creating or updating files as suggested) at the following links:

- [Wifi LED continuously blinking UBUNTU 14.04 and slowed connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451178/wifi-led-continuously-blinking-ubuntu-14-04-and-slowed-connection)
- [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

For example, on my system (HP G60, with Ubuntu Mate 14.04 64-bit install), I opened the file /etc/modprobe.d/wlan.conf in pluma, and it had 3 lines in which led_mode=1 existed.

Some of the other advice, mentioned `MODULE NAME` and that mine would be listed below. It didn't seem to list any for 14.04, how would I know what the module name is for Ubuntu Mate 14.04 specifically?

I realize this question may be difficult to answer without a dump from `lspci`, which I will do later this evening once I get home. I know only at this time it is Atheros.

Thanks in advance,
Adam

[[appending info below, based on answer]] - I was able to determine module name as "ath5k"

```
$ modinfo ath5k
```

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-44-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/ath5k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for 5xxx series of Atheros 802.11 wireless LAN cards.

...
parm:           no_hw_rfkill_switch:Ignore the GPIO RFKill switch state (bool)

the file /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi,conf already contained (as the last line in the file)

```
options iwlwifi led_mode=1
```

So, i'm not sure how to proceed at this point. Do I seek the electrical tape? LOL

Edit (March 12, 2015) Got the annoying blink to stop. Found at [Wireless LED doesn't stop blinking on an HP dv5 with an Atheros AR5007](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88103/wireless-led-doesnt-stop-blinking-on-an-hp-dv5-with-an-atheros-ar5007)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module name is found in:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Here is a redacted example from my computer:

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 35
       serial: xx:94:6b:99:55:xx
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-31
```

As you can see, the driver is *iwlwifi*, in this example.

Now, as to whether we can control the LED, we turn to: `modinfo <your_driver>`, in this example *iwlwifi*. We see, in part:

```
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
```

Therefor, if we wish to change the behavior of the LED, we would add to the already existing iwlwifi.conf file:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi led_mode=3"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

In the case of many drivers, the behavior is not manipulable; in some cases, the driver parameter is found in one of the driver's dependencies. In my example, iwlwifi also loads iwldvm, cfg80211 and mac80211. I find this in:

```
lsmod | grep iwl
```

If I saw no method to change the LED behavior in iwlwifi, I'd check every dependency. In some cases, the only option is electrical tape.

Once you know your driver, if you get stuck, post back and I'll be happy to assist.

Again, in the case of many drivers, the behavior is not manipulable.

Comment: sorry but the steps you mentioned have not helped the blinking light annoyance. I'm looking for painters tape as it is less tacky than electrical tape

Comment: I think I found something that worked. Even though the version stated is 11.10, the advice of first issuing some /sys/class commands, and (provided they worked) add them to a shell script - seemed to work!! My LED is solid blue instead of blinking!! http://askubuntu.com/questions/88103/wireless-led-doesnt-stop-blinking-on-an-hp-dv5-with-an-atheros-ar5007